# Osm2po missing some streets in SF

Tags: routing, osm2po

I recently used osm2po (v 5.0.0) on SF with these parameters:
java -Xmx8g -jar osm2po-core.jar cmd=tjspg prefix=sf tileSize=x california-latest.osm.pbf

and everything looks great in the whole city except for some streets around Mission and 2nd. I've added a picture for illustration, streets that are not colored are not in the sf_2po_4pgr table. Is there something I'm missing in terms of params - maybe different tileSize?

The only change I've done in the config is added a vertex writer:
postp.1.class = de.cm.osm2po.plugins.PgVertexWriter

[image]

Comment: Do you have the latest pbf? Do you see a schema of the missing streets? E.g. only highway=track or similar? Or compare with GraphHopper if they will be correctly routed over.

Comment: Yeah, it's the latest pbf, and these streets should be there...

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem importing Romania and Hungary sql files but not in the case of US imports. The problem was that some segments were not inserted because of an encoding problem. Solved this by changing the client encoding to UTF8 in the psql console. The code I used looks like this:

```
mydatabase-# \encoding UTF8
mydatabase-# \i d:/countryname_2po_4pgr.sql
```